# Minimal Chess Web GUI with Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinventing-the-wheel, chess, flask

Being a big chess fan, I finally started developing my own chess tool, however I'm already quite dissatisfied with where it's going...

folder structure:

```
E:.
|   index.py
|
+---static
|   |   script.js
|   |   styles.css
|   |
|   \---pieces
|           bb.svg
|           bk.svg
|           bn.svg
|           bp.svg
|           bq.svg
|           br.svg
|           wB.svg
|           wK.svg
|           wN.svg
|           wP.svg
|           wQ.svg
|           wR.svg
|
+---templates
|       index.html
```

index.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
import chess

app = Flask(__name__)

CHESS_BOARD = chess.Board()
LAST_CLICKED_SQUARE = None


def invert_index(index):
    return (7 - index // 8) * 8 + index % 8


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html', board=CHESS_BOARD)


@app.route('/legal_moves/<int:index>')
def legal_moves(index):
    global LAST_CLICKED_SQUARE

    LAST_CLICKED_SQUARE = (index := invert_index(index))
    moves = [
        move.to_square for move in CHESS_BOARD.legal_moves
        if move.from_square == index
    ]

    return jsonify(moves)


@app.route('/make_move/<int:index>', methods=['POST'])
def make_move(index):
    # noinspection PyTypeChecker
    CHESS_BOARD.push(chess.Move(LAST_CLICKED_SQUARE, invert_index(index)))
    return jsonify(CHESS_BOARD.fen())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="chess-container">
        <div class="file-labels">
            {% for file in 'abcdefgh' %}
                <div class="label">{{ file }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="rank-labels">
            {% for i in range(8, 0, -1) %}
                <div class="label">{{ i }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="chess-board">
            {% for i in range(7, -1, -1) %}
                {% for j in range(8) %}
                    <div class="{{ 'white' if (i+j)%2==1 else 'black' }}">
                        {% set piece = board.piece_at(i*8+j) %}
                        {% if piece %}
                            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='pieces/' + ('w' if piece.color else 'b') + piece|string + '.svg') }}">
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="rank-labels2">
            {% for i in range(8, 0, -1) %}
                <div class="label">{{ i }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="file-labels2">
            {% for file in 'abcdefgh' %}
                <div class="label">{{ file }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    background: #eee;
}

.chess-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30px auto 30px;
    grid-template-rows: 30px auto 30px;
    gap: 0px 0px;
    grid-template-areas:
        ". files ."
        "ranks chess-board ranks2"
        ". files2 .";
}

.chess-board {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    grid-area: chess-board;
}

.rank-labels {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: ranks;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 28px;
    padding-bottom: 28px;
}

.rank-labels2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: ranks2;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-top: 28px;
    padding-bottom: 28px;

}

.file-labels {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: files;
    padding-left: 28px;
    padding-right: 28px;
}

.file-labels2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    grid-area: files2;
    padding-left: 28px;
    padding-right: 28px;
}

.label {
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.chess-board div {
    position: relative;
}

.chess-board div::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;
}

.chess-board div.black {
    background: #b58863;
}

.chess-board div.white {
    background: #f0d9b5;
}

.chess-board div img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
}

.chess-board div.highlight {
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

script.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    let squares = document.querySelectorAll(".chess-board div");
    squares.forEach((square, index) => {
        square.addEventListener("click", function() {
            if (square.classList.contains("highlight")) {
                // Move the piece and update the board
                fetch('/make_move/' + index, {
                        method: 'POST'
                    })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(fen => {
                        squares.forEach(square => {
                            square.classList.remove("highlight");
                            let img = square.querySelector("img");
                            if (img) img.remove();
                        });
                        fen.split(" ")[0].split("/").forEach((row, i) => {
                            row.replace(/\d/g, m => " ".repeat(m)).split("").forEach((cell, j) => {
                                if (cell !== " ") {
                                    let img = document.createElement("img");
                                    img.src = `/static/pieces/${cell === cell.toUpperCase() ? 'w' : 'b'}${cell.toLowerCase()}.svg`;
                                    squares[8 * i + j].appendChild(img);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
            } else {
                fetch('/legal_moves/' + index)
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        squares.forEach(square => square.classList.remove("highlight"));
                        data.forEach(i => squares[(7 - Math.floor(i / 8)) * 8 + i % 8].classList.add("highlight")); // Correct for board orientation
                    });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

---

Things I wish I knew how to do better:

- Avoiding global variables in the index.py (maybe somehow putting everything into a class? But that doesn't seem to work with Flask for me...)
- Avoiding double definitions of .file-labels and .rank-labels just so I can put it both at the top and bottom/left and right. (This was the only way I found to get it to work)
- I have never programmed anything in JavaScript so I'm just in disbelief at the 10th indentation level and how unreadable the whole thing is :(

---

Final result

[image: Final result]

Comment: Re your JavaScript woes, could [this](https://dev.to/johnpaulada/synchronous-fetch-with-asyncawait) help?